# Default Document preview is not working in share point 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, display-template

I am using the search result web part to display the results. But in my case, the document icon is showing but the document preview is not showing. When I further debugged, it clearly shows that the ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL is null and all other ServerRedirectedPreviewURL and ServerRedirectedURL are also null. I have done full crawl from **central admin**. Changed the **Result type** and updated it. Even deleted the display template and uploaded it again. what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

something happened to your Office Online Server, or Office Web Apps server, you may need to check on the status of that and check the bindings using PowerShell (as Administrator):

On the OWA/OOS server:
`Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm`

On the SP Server:
`Get-SPWOPIBinding`

If either of those don't produce results, then you need to rebuild your OWA/OOS server and connection with SharePoint. You can follow an article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx)

Comment: we are not using any OOS or OWA server.

Comment: By default, the preview documents feature will come right?

Comment: so in the SP server I tried with the commands in the link which you gave. But nothing worked for me.

Comment: Used Get-SPWOPIBinding -Server "Server.corp.Contoso.com" command and it returned nothing in the SP Server.

Comment: just try `Get-SPWOPIBinding` with no parameters and no the preview feature does not automatically come with SharePoint Server

Comment: I have tried the Get-SPWOPIBinding command but it returned nothing

Comment: I have used (<object data="_#= $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Path) =#_" type="application/pdf" width="280px" height="430px"></object>) . Only the pdf files is working but for other files like word/excel it is not working.

Comment: Right--because PDFs have content types (application/pdf) that your browser knows how to handle. you will need to find out if you have an office web apps (or Office Online) server. If it used to work and now doesnt, you need to recreate the binding. If it never worked then you probably need to set up a new Office Web Apps or Office Online server.

Comment: I am not having any OOS or OWA server

Comment: Then you need to build one.

Comment: But when the site is created in onpremise , document preview is worked for me

Comment: As it is the default feature.

Comment: And how to recreate the binding?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running?

Comment: sharepoint 2016

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt668456(v=office.16).aspx If it used to work, you have an Office Online server somewhere, but the binding was removed, unless the server was removed.

Comment: I didn't have any OOS or OWA server and never configured it for my SP server..

Comment: Document Preview worked for me by default...

Comment: As far as my understanding, my guess is you were either on another farm, or on SharePoint Online, because to my knowledge document preview won't work without Office Web Apps

Comment: As per my understandings, I am missing a small configuration or feature in share point 2016 before customizing display template and after customizing.